# Python How to use extended path length

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am running my python code on Windows and trying to traverse and store all the file name with their paths in a file. But the Windows has a restriction of 260 characters.

```
os.chdir(self.config.Root_Directory_Path())        
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk("."):
        file_list.extend( join(root,f) for f in files )
    file_name_sorted = sorted(file_list)
    #file_sorted = sorted(file_list, key=getsize)
    #time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p" ,time.localtime(os.path.getmtime(file)))
    f = open(self.config.Client_Local_Status(),'wb')        
    for file_name in file_name_sorted:
        if (os.path.exists(file_name)):
            #f.write((str(os.path.getmtime(file_name)) + "|" + file_name + "\n").encode('utf-8'))
            pass
        else:
            print(file_name + "|" + str(len(file_name) + len(originalPath)) + "\n")
            print(os.path.getmtime(file_name))
            #f.write((str(os.path.getmtime(file_name)) + "|" + file_name + "\n").encode('utf-8'))
    f.close()
```

Because of the error, os.path.getmtime(file_name) throws an exception file not found. How can I overcome this problem? I tried using //?/ character as prefix, as suggested in

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx

But was not successful in using //?/ character.

I tried using os.path.getmtime("////?//" + file_name) #Threw an error invalid path

Please suggest a fix

Comment: @PedroRomano No problem. Thanks... Looking forward for some help

Comment: @PedroRomano I have been looking for solution like a mad for almost 2 days now. Please upvote this so if you like the question so that I want many people get to see this. Thanks

Comment: If you're using forward slashes, do not double them like that. It's only backslashes that need to be doubled, because backslash is the escape character for (non-raw) strings; slash is a perfectly normal character. Try just doing `'//?/'` instead of `'////?//'` and see what happens.

Comment: Also, I think you can only use \\?\ with absolute paths. From your comment to Pedro Romano's answer, you seem to have a relative path starting with `./`. Try doing `os.path.abspath(file_name)` in place of `file_name`.

Comment: Since the answer I'd added other comments to got deleted, let me repeat the important bit here: You cannot do `r'\\?\\'`, because that will end up with an extra backslash, making the path invalid. If forward slashes don't work (with `abspath`), try just `\\\\?\\` (again with `abspath`).

Comment: @abarnet, I tried print(os.path.getmtime(r'\\?\\' + os.path.abspath(file_name))) and it looks it is working. I would encourage you to post this answer. Thanks... I will do bit more of testing and gladly accept your answer. Thanks

Comment: @PedroRomano Thanks for all your help mate... I appreciate your efforts. I would request you to delete your answer though.

Comment: Already deleted. It was silly to have attempted an answer because I don't have Windows and couldn't really test my answer properly. The solution I published in the answer was actually working on Windows Python running on Linux on Wine, but I can't really expect the behaviour there to be the same it is on real Windows.

Comment: @PedroRomano: Were you testing with his code, or with a simple test that already had an absolute path?

Comment: @abarnet: I tested with a path I created, but Wine (or at least the Wine `cmd`) apparently can't handle paths longer than 255 characters (I started to get errors when I created a path longer than 255). Anyway, served me right for publishing answers I can't test! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem here is that you're using a relative path. The `\\?\` prefix can only be applied to absolute paths. As [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx#maxpath) says:

> These prefixes are not used as part of the path itself. They indicate that the path should be passed to the system with minimal modification, which means that you cannot use forward slashes to represent path separators, or a period to represent the current directory, or double dots to represent the parent directory. Because you cannot use the "`\\?\`" prefix with a relative path, relative paths are always limited to a total of **MAX_PATH** characters.

The fix is simple. Instead of this:

```
'\\\\?\\' + file_name
```

do this:

```
'\\\\?\\' + os.path.abspath(file_name)
```

You cannot use forward slashes. It may or may not be legal to add an extra backslash, in which case you can get away with `r'\\?\\'` instead of doubling the double backslash. Try it and see (but make sure to test both drive-prefixed paths like `C:\foo` and UNC paths like `\\server\share\bar`)… But the doubled-backslash version above should definitely work.

Comment: @abarnet: I actually always used an absolute (literal) path in my tests. It never occurred to me that @Romaan would be using relative paths. That was what threw me off. I guess `os.path.join(r'\\?\\', os.path.abspath(very_long_file_name))` would actually work, then. Anyway +1 for your excellent answer.

Comment: @PedroRomano: I suppose it should be obvious from his code that he had relative paths… but it wasn't obvious to me. I didn't notice until one of his responses to one of your comments. So, I wouldn't feel too bad that it wasn't obvious to you either. Anyway, we figured it out eventually.